# Is there a nice way to implement a conditional type with default fail case?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits, conditional-types

For implementing a conditional type I highly enjoy [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) as it keeps the code short and very readable:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using bit_type =
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{  8 }, std::uint8_t,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 16 }, std::uint16_t,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 32 }, std::uint32_t, 
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 64 }, std::uint64_t, void>>>>;
```

using it works quite intuitively:

```
bit_type<8u> a;  // == std::uint8_t
bit_type<16u> b; // == std::uint16_t
bit_type<32u> c; // == std::uint32_t
bit_type<64u> d; // == std::uint64_t
```

But since this is a pure conditional type there must be a default type - `void`, in this case. Therefore if `N` is any other value said type yields:

```
bit_type<500u> f; // == void
```

Now this doesn't compile, but the yielding type is still valid.

Meaning you could say `bit_type<500u>* f;` and would have a valid program!

So is there a nice way to let compilation fail when the fail case of an conditional type is reached?

---

One idea immediately would be to replace the last `std::conditional_t` with [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template<std::size_t N>
using bit_type =
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{  8 }, std::uint8_t,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 16 }, std::uint16_t,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 32 }, std::uint32_t, 
    std::enable_if_t<  N == std::size_t{ 64 }, std::uint64_t>>>>;
```

The problem with that is that templates are always fully evaluated, meaning that the `std::enable_if_t` is always fully evaluated - and that will fail if `N != std::size_t{ 64 }`. Urgh.

---

My current go-to workaround to this is rather clumsy introducing a struct and 3 `using` declarations:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct bit_type {
private:
    using vtype =
        std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 8 }, std::uint8_t,
        std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 16 }, std::uint16_t,
        std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 32 }, std::uint32_t,
        std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 64 }, std::uint64_t, void>>>>;

public:
    using type = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<vtype, void>, vtype>;
};

template<std::size_t N>
using bit_type_t = bit_type<N>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<bit_type_t<64u>, std::uint64_t>, "");
```

Which generally works, but I dislike it as it adds so much stuff, I might as well just use template specialization. It also reserves `void` as a special type - so it won't work where `void` is actually a yield from a branch. Is there a readable, short solution?

Comment: Why `N == std::size_t{8}` instead of `N == 8`?  Are you afraid that `std::size_t` isn't capable of holding `8`?

Comment: @L.F. probably he what to prevent warning of comparing types with different sign.

Comment: @MarekR Hmm ... I get no warnings with `N == 8` under `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`.  Maybe the warning is suppressed automatically for literals that presumably do not cause problems?

Comment: I always try keep the number of casts low, I know it's not necessary in a constant compile time context - but it's my habit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a level of indirection, so that the result of the outermost `conditional_t` is not a type but a metafunction that needs `::type` to be applied to it. Then use `enable_if` instead of `enable_if_t` so you don't access the `::type` unless it's actually needed:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
using bit_type = typename
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{  8 }, std::type_identity<std::uint8_t>,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 16 }, std::type_identity<std::uint16_t>,
    std::conditional_t<N == std::size_t{ 32 }, std::type_identity<std::uint32_t>, 
    std::enable_if<N == std::size_t{ 64 }, std::uint64_t>>>>::type;
```

In this version, the type in the final branch is `enable_if<``condition``, uint64_t>` which is always a valid type, and you only get an error if that branch is actually taken and `enable_if<false, uint64_t>::type` is needed.

When one of the earlier branches is taken, you end up using `std::type_identity<uintNN_t>::type` for one of the smaller integer types, and it doesn't matter that `enable_if<false, uint64_t>` has no nested type (because you don't use it).

---

If you are not using C++20 and `std::type_identity` is not available, you can make your own:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct type_identity { using type = T; };
```

Comment: So this would be a rare case where the `_t` version actually has a downside. Interesting, thanks!

Comment: `::type` should be before `>>>` or use `std::std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: @MarekR No, that way `conditional` operates on the (nonexistent) `::type`.  And then the entire `identity` is superfluous.

Comment: @L.F. there is `std::conditional_t` not `std::conditional` so ... .

Comment: @MarekR `conditional_t` gets the type to apply `::type` on, so you would otherwise write `typename conditional<...>::type::type`.  If this sounds confusing, it is!

Comment: @MarekR instead of trying to suggest fixes please compile my code, and try compiling your "fixed" version. You'll find out which one meets the OP's requirement and which one doesn't. My answer does explain why it's done this way, and why it works.

Comment: Ok it compiles but its weird (mixing `intX_t` with `std::enable_if` types and adding this `indentity` instead having only `intX_t` in the chain). IMO this is simpler: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7jdTzfjIR8VyN8Zg

Comment: @MarekR but I don't mix `intN_t` and `enable_if`, I mix `identity<intN_t>` and `enable_if<C, intN_t>`. Because you need to add a level of indirection. Read the question. Read the answer. Your version is simpler **but doesn't work: https://wandbox.org/permlink/0LKosKXj50Y9hX1j**

Comment: @MarekR `std::conditional` works only when its arguments are both valid.  In the answer's case, `enable_if<...>` the type itself is valid (whether it has a `type` member doesn't affect its validity).  In your case, the `enable_if_t<...>` is invalid because it is equivalent to `enable_if<...>::type`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun... what about using `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_element` avoiding at all `std::conditional`?

If you can use C++14 (so template variables and specialization of template variables) you can write a template variable for conversion size/index-in-the-tuple

```
template <std::size_t>
constexpr std::size_t  bt_index = 100u; // bad value

template <> constexpr std::size_t  bt_index<8u>  = 0u; 
template <> constexpr std::size_t  bt_index<16u> = 1u; 
template <> constexpr std::size_t  bt_index<32u> = 2u; 
template <> constexpr std::size_t  bt_index<64u> = 3u;
```

so `bit_type` become

```
template <std::size_t N>
using bit_type = std::tuple_element_t<bt_index<N>,
   std::tuple<std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>>;
```

If you can use only C++11, you can develop a `bt_index()` `constexpr` function that return the correct (or incorrect) value.

You can verify that are satisfied

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<bit_type<8u>,  std::uint8_t>, "!" );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<bit_type<16u>, std::uint16_t>, "!" );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<bit_type<32u>, std::uint32_t>, "!" );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<bit_type<64u>, std::uint64_t>, "!" );
```

and that using `bit_type` with an unsupported dimension

```
bit_type<42u> * pbt42;
```

cause a compilation error.

**-- EDIT --** As suggested by Jonathan Wakely, if you can use C++20, so `std::has_single_bit()` (formerly `std::ispow2()`) and `std::bit_width()` (formerly `std::log2p1()`), you can simplify a lot: you can avoid `bt_index` at all and simply write

```
template <std::size_t N>
using bit_type = std::tuple_element_t<std::has_single_bit(N) ? std::bit_width(N)-4u : -1,
   std::tuple<std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>>;
```

Comment: Neat alternative! I suppose it might increase compilation time for large cases due to `std::tuple`'s allignement nature, which isn't needed here.

Comment: N.B. In C++20 you should be able to do `template <std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t  bt_index = std::ispow2(N) ? std::log2p1(N) - 4 : -1;` (i.e. without specializing the variable template).

Comment: @JonathanWakely - Exactly what I was looking for; thanks! Given `std::ispow2()` and `std::log2p1()` you can avoid `bt_index` at all and use your expression directly as first argument for `std::tuple_element`.

Comment: You can indeed :-)